# Can't log in to my web app due to a SemaphoreFullException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, webforms, semaphore

All of a sudden, when I try to log in to my VB.NET Web Forms app, I get this error:

> System.Threading.SemaphoreFullException: Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count.

The line of code that threw this exception is:

`myTemp2Reader.Close()`

Why would closing a `DataReader` throw this exception, and how can I stop it from doing so?

This started a little while ago when I noticed that after making some changes to the code, I could no longer hit breakpoints when debugging. I undid the changes, but that didn't help. So I reset IIS and I think that's when the semaphore thing started...

Comment: Please a semaphore-specific tag. There are a few to choose from.

Comment: And now I can log in... I guess I had to let my connections time out or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add “Pooling=False” condition to connection string then it will disable the connection pool and run the application without any problem.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="dbconnection" connectionString="Data Source=SureshDasari; Initial Catalog=TestDatabase; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=test; Pooling=False;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

refer this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013179/semaphore-exception-adding-the-specified-count-to-the-semaphore-would-cause-it) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013179/semaphore-exception-adding-the-specified-count-to-the-semaphore-would-cause-it) for more detail.